# condition using ngTemplateOutlet && ng-template ignored

Tags: angular, typescript

I have condition using to show/not show my data.
there are 2 problems with the code:

1. if the condition `[ngIf]="df == 'srCreationDate'"` false, it's noe effect the data (like there is no condition)
2. I have to iterate the loop just one time, but when I am adding | slice:0:1 pipe nothing appears

   ```
   <ng-template #titleCreationDate>
   <div mat-sort-header="srCreationDate"></div>
   </ng-template>

   <ng-container *ngFor="let df of dynamicFields ">
   <ng-container [ngIf]="df == 'srCreationDate'" *ngTemplateOutlet="titleCreationDate"></ng-container></ng-container>
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct template code that you should be using:

```
  <ng-template #titleCreationDate>
    <div mat-sort-header="srCreationDate"></div>
  </ng-template>

  <ng-container *ngFor="let df of dynamicFields ">
    <ng-container *ngIf="df === 'srCreationDate'">
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="titleCreationDate">
      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
  </ng-container>
```

StackBlitz [**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9b6z9e?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).